# Image not properly loaded in PolygonImageView using Glide

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, android-glide

I am trying to load the image in polygon ImageView using glide library here is the code

```
GlideApp.with(Activity.this)
 .load(path)
 .placeholder(R.drawable.user_avatar)
 .into(polygonImageView);
```

When i using this code result is in below image (the image is cut from right and bottom) 
 [image: Result]

But i want this as result 
[image: Expected[2]]

For Polygon ImageView using third party library [Click Here to Check Library](https://github.com/hangox/PolygonImageView)

Any Help from you will be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am Refered That `PolyGon Imageview Library` But Issue was not There.

Just Use This Code It ll be Works Like a Charm

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
options.centerCrop();
Glide.with(this)
            .load("your URL")
            .apply(options)
            .into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview));
```